# How do I successfully Connect to MySQL from netcore. ASP C# on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: c#, mysql, nuget, .net-core, ubuntu-16.04

I followed the instructions from this link

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/html/connector-net-x-devapi-reference.htm

AS shown below. (Program.cs File)

```
using MySql.XDevAPI;
using MySql.XDevAPI.Common;
using MySql.XDevAPI.CRUD;
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace consoleApp
{
    public  class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // string schemaName = "world_x";
            string schemaName = "sakila";

            string connectionString = "server=localhost;port=3306;uid=username;password=";    
            Session session = MySQLX.GetSession(connectionString);
            Schema schema = session.GetSchema(schemaName);

            // Use the collection 'customer'
            var myCollection = schema.GetCollection("customer");
            var docParams = new DbDoc(new { name1 = "MARY", _id1 = "1" });

            // Find a document
            DocResult foundDocs = myCollection.Find("first_name = :name1|| store_id = :_id1").Bind(docParams).Execute();

            while (foundDocs.Next())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(foundDocs.Current["Name"]);
                Console.WriteLine(foundDocs.Current["_id"]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also ConsoleApp.csproj file

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Google.Protobuf" Version="3.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MySql.Data" Version="8.0.8-dmr" />
    <PackageReference Include="MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.8-dmr" />
    <PackageReference Include="MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="8.0.8-dmr" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

appsettings.json file

```
{
"ConnectionStrings":
 {
    "SampleConnection": "server=localhost;userid=username;pwd=;port=3306;database=sakila;sslmode=none;"
 }
}
```

using a simple Console Application first of all instead of the web to streamline what's wrong

But After all I keep getting the following errors

=====================================================================

```
dotnet build
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.1.1012.6693
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Program.cs(1,13): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'XDevAPI' does not exist in the namespace 'MySql' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [/home/filePath/consoleApp/consoleApp.csproj]
Program.cs(2,13): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'XDevAPI' does not exist in the namespace 'MySql' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [/home/filePath/consoleApp/consoleApp.csproj]
Program.cs(3,13): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'XDevAPI' does not exist in the namespace 'MySql' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [/home/filePath/consoleApp/consoleApp.csproj]

Build FAILED.

Program.cs(1,13): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'XDevAPI' does not exist in the namespace 'MySql' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [/home/filePath/consoleApp/consoleApp.csproj]
Program.cs(2,13): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'XDevAPI' does not exist in the namespace 'MySql' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [/home/filePath/consoleApp/consoleApp.csproj]
Program.cs(3,13): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'XDevAPI' does not exist in the namespace 'MySql' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [/home/filePath/consoleApp/consoleApp.csproj]
    0 Warning(s)
    3 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:02.00
```

=====================================================================

Is there something I am missing or that I did not install or what? !
Please I really need help here to figure out what is wrong.
Thanks!

Comment: You tagged asp.net-core-mvc here, but you're using a .NET Core Console Application.

Comment: oh thanks for noting that, I am using .netcore  console application here to figure out how to connect before using it in the .netcore web application
#editing it right away. :)

Comment: @JanesAbouChleih please do you use windows os to develop your C# web applications only or you also use Linux based OS like Ubuntu ?

Comment: I'm on Windows. Also having trouble getting it running. mscorlib is required - which is a sign that it's not running on .NET Core/Standard but the full .NET Framework. Are you sure that MySql.XDevAPI is .NET Core compatible?